# Problema al crear variable publica VBA ACCESS

Tags: vba, ms-access

Buenas tardes estoy intentando crear dos variables publicas para luego usarlas en todos mis formularios . Tengo entendido que se hacen en unua modulo independiente pero ahora no se como guardarlo ni se como llamar al modulo desde mis formularios esto es lo que e hecho hasta ahora (modulo independiente):

Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Public nom As String
Public nro As String

Agradeceria ayuda, gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se hace así Arturo:

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Database
Public nom As String
Public nro As String
Sub Test()

'Código

End Sub
```

Aunque te recomiendo no utilizar variables públicas ya que cualquier procedimiento puede cambiar sus valores, la buena práctica sería pasar esas variables como parámetros:

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Database
Sub Test()

    Dim nom As String
    Dim nro As String

    'Código

    Test2 nom, nro

End Sub
Sub Test2(nom As String, nro As String)    

    'Código  

End Sub
```

Puedes pasar las variables como `ByVal`, sólo das el valor de la variable, aunque tú luego lo cambies en `Test2` no cambiará el valor original de la variable en `Test`.

También puedes pasar las variables como `ByRef` (por defecto si no se especifica) lo que hace que si cambias el valor de alguna variable en `Test2` también se cambia en `Test`.

Por último, debes tener en cuenta que si en `Test2` declaras la variable como `String` el parámetro que le pases también debe ser declarado como `String` o te dará un  `Type Mismatch`.

Comment: Bien optaria por lo segundo pero parte de la duda sigue: como guardo el modulo (si es que hay que guardarlo) y como lo llamo desde los modulos de los diferentes formularios,, Gracias.. por tu atencion..

Comment: @Arturo los módulos una vez insertados se quedan ahí siempre (mientras guardes el archivo) y para llamarlos no necesitas hacer nada especial, como te muestro en el ejemplo, pones el nombre de la macro y seguidos los parámetros separados por coma.

Comment: Gracias Damian voy a probar todo esto. Saludos